# Merge two plots while fix axis elements

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, dendrogram

I want to merge a tileplot (from *tile* object) and a dendrogram (from *dendro* object) while fixing all the elements on y axis at the same place.

With a small reproducible example of data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dendextend)
library(ggpubr)

df <- tibble(
Method=c("kbest_f","fpr_chi2","perc_f","kbest_chi2","fpr_chi2","perc_mutual","perc_f","perc_mutual","fpr_chi2","fpr_chi2"),
Coincidence = c("AVV","ENH","MPN","WET","TKR","LEA","SPQ","PIY","VYL","AGL"), n=rep(1,10))

scores <- with(df, table(Coincidence, Method))
dendro <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(scores, method="binary"), method="ward.D"))

tile <- df %>%
    mutate(Coincidence = factor(Coincidence,levels=partition_leaves(dendro)[[1]]))
```

I've managed to generate these two plots:

```
tileplot <- tile %>%
    ggplot(aes(Method, Coincidence, fill= n)) + 
  geom_tile()+
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
        angle = 90,
        vjust = 0.5,
        hjust=1),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size=5),
    legend.position="none")

dendroplot <- 
    ggdendrogram(
        dendro,
        rotate=TRUE)+
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(
          size = 5,
          vjust = 0.5,
              hjust = 1.0))
```

Finally:

```
ggarrange(
    tileplot,
    dendroplot,
    labels=c("A","B"),
    ncol=2,
    nrow=1)
```

While using *ggarrange* to merge *tileplot* and *dendroplot* generates the correct array, the size of the y-axis dendrogram needs to be shorter, so that all labels remain at the corresponding level.

So, **how can I adjust them**?

P.D:  Default options of heatmap() functions do not show all the elements i need at the way i need.

Comment: Did you look at heatmaply? It might give you the control you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use `plot_grid()` from the `cowplot` package.  `cowplot::plot_grid()` allows you to arrange and align plots in a grid. 
 Specifically, the `align = "h"` option allows plots to be drawn with horizontal alignment, which means that the y-axes of plots in the same row have the same lengths on the grid.

```r
library(cowplot)

plot_grid(tileplot, dendroplot, labels = "AUTO", align = "h")
```

[image]

Reference: https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/plot_grid.html

Comment: This answer works well, but for many data I've used the argument scale=c(1,1.096) for a better aligning.